# How to add styling (CSS) to <img> tags in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following `_renderItem` function in jquery where it has `<img>` tags with inline attributes **height** and **width**. However these attributes are NOT working in internet explorer as IE would require them to be written in CSS.
So, how do I insert that styling in here?

Following is `renderItem`function.

```
.data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
         return $('<li>')                                  
        .data('item.autocomplete', item)
        .append("<a>"+"<img src ='/account/"+item.id+"/icon/logo' onerror='$(this).hide()' height='40' width='40' alt=''/>" + " " + " " +item.label+"</a>")
        .appendTo(ul); 

 };
```

Comment: so you're saying that `height='40' width='40'` works everywhere except IE?

Comment: yes, inline attributes won't tend to work in IE, unfortunately

Comment: IE would require them to be written in CSS  means?

Comment: why can't you write   style='height:40px;width:40px' instead of inline attributes.

Comment: Here I am using inline attributes for resizing image (which normally works in chrome, mozilla etc) but in case of IE, they should be written as inline STYLING like <img style ="height:30px; width:40px"> in order to work. But this is javascript, I am not sure who to write styling.

Comment: @Ammu have you tried the solutions...?

Comment: Can I know why this has been voted down?

Comment: Expected a Duplicate question link here :/ But two answers

Comment: Can I please have the link of that  duplicate question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace inline attributes

```
  height='40' width='40'
```

with inline css like this

```
    .data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
             return $('<li>')                                  
            .data('item.autocomplete', item)
            .append("<a>"+"<img src ='/account/"+item.id+"/icon/logo' onerror='$(this).hide()' style='width:40px;height:40px' alt=''/>" + " " + " " +item.label+"</a>")
            .appendTo(ul); 

     };
```

Comment: This is working! Thanks! I  just didn't know how to use those inline styling in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
.data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    var imgLink = $('<a>' + item.label + '</a>')
        .append($('<img />', {
            'src': '/account/' + item.id + '/icon/logo',
            'style': 'width:40px; height:40px;',
            onerror: function() {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        }));

    return $('<li>')
        .data('item.autocomplete', item)
        .append(imgLink)
        .appendTo(ul);

};
```

Comment: This is picking up the parsing error at `'onerror': '$(this).hide()',` line

Comment: It is because I missed the comma before `onerror` function, fixed now